# python how to get acces to variable from other class

Tags: python, class, variables

It's me again. I want to get access to variable `deck` from `class Deck` in `class Table` in method `howManyCards`. In other words I create a deck of cards, and I want to do a method which let me take a `num` of firsts cards from the deck list and I dont know how to write this properly. Line `self.onTheTable = Deck.deck[:num]` doesn't work. I have an error `AttributeError: type object 'Deck' has no attribute 'deck'` which I understand, but I dont know how to change that in right way. Thank you.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, figure, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.figure = figure
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.figure) + str(self.colour)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
    def createDeck(self):
        for colour in ["h", "d", "c", "s"]:
            for figure in ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]:
                self.deck.append(Card(figure, colour))

class Table():
    def __init__(self):
        self.onTheTable = []
    def howManyCards(self, num):
       self.onTheTable = Deck.deck[:num]

deck = Deck()
deck.createDeck()
table = Table()
table.howManyCards(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MobileBen pointed out, you are not accessing the Deck object.

You could use protected variable names and `@property` decorators to provide public read-only access to internal variables.

You could also pass the Deck instance used with that Table object during the initialization of the class.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self._deck = []    # Protected member starting with _

    def createDeck(self):
        for colour in ["h", "d", "c", "s"]:
            for figure in ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]:
                self._deck.append(Card(figure, colour))

    @property
    def deck(self):
        return self._deck


class Table():
    def __init__(self, deck):
        self._onTheTable = []
        self._deck = deck

    def howManyCards(self, num):
       self._onTheTable = self._deck.deck[:num]

    @property
    def onTheTable(self):
       return self._onTheTable

deck = Deck()
deck.createDeck()
table = Table(deck)
table.howManyCards(10)

print(table.onTheTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two changes:

```
def howManyCards(self, deck, num):
   self.onTheTable = deck.deck[:num]
```

`table.howManyCards(deck, 10)`

The problem with your original code (`Deck.deck[:num]`) as it is is that you are treating `deck` as a class variable. `deck` is an instance variable.

Comment: Yes, I have a problem with understanding what is going on, but I am fighting. Thanks, that works.

Comment: It's the effort that counts. Keep at it and it will make more sense. You can check this out for more details on class and instance variables. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables